# Weird issue on AJAX register form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function like this on my register page.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tryRegister").click(function()
        {
            $("#result").html('<img src="<%THEME%>images/loading.gif">');
            var formData = $("#regForm").serialize();
            $.post("?page=register&do=1", formData, function(data)
            {
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

The button I use to submit values is:

```
<input type="button" id="tryRegister" value="<:REG_SUBMIT:>"/>
```

The PHP controls are like the following:

```
//Get POST values, appoint to variables/sanitize them

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT AccountID FROM USERS WHERE AccountID = ?', $user);
if ($num_rows > 0)
{
    $this->Error('REG_USER_IN_USE');
    return;
}

//If everything is correct, add user into database.
$this->Error('REG_SUCCESS');
```

Error function only echoes the input after getting it's language value. Nothing important in this case:

**The Issue**

When I successfully register, it announce "Username is taken." instead of "You have registered successfully!" The member account doesn't exist in the database before, and it exists after the successfuly registration.

The PHP side seems to be correct. (as it works without ajax) It could be related to jQuery function, perhabs it quickly requests twice or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure doQuery returns nothing when success?

Comment: It should return 0 value since the account ID in database is non-existant, hence, REG_USER_IN_USE shouldn't be the output.

Comment: Is doQuery a function of your creation? If so, can you post its code? This just looks to me like you're getting a boolean back from the doQuery call when it indicates that a database query was successful. In PHP I believe a (true > 0) comparison will return true.

Comment: I think I've found the reason. Strangely, the PHP script works twice. For example, if I do echo "1"; it output 11. I believe once I figure it out, the problem will be solved. (Have no idea why it does btw. There is no loops or nothing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very old but I wanted to share the solution. The issue was PHP controller running twice. The service locator model was calling it twice, mostly due to timing missmatch on my cache implementation.

Think it like;

```
$controller->Run();
if(cache === true)
    $controller->Run();
```

Both of the methods run, so user successfully registers on first call. On the second call, it notices username is taken and responds "Username is taken."